# Add Name to Array using setState gives error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Im trying to add an item to an array in my state. However, i get the following error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys...)

My [github url](https://github.com/myhendry/playground_rn) to the codes, Please help.

```
class Tutorial2Screen extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         num: 0,
         name: "",
         arr: ["John", "Mary", "Steve"]
      };
   }

   addNameToArr(newName) {
      this.setState(prevState => ({
         arr: prevState.arr.concat(newName)
      }));
   }
```

Input & Button codes:

```
<Input
   placeholder="Name"
   onChangeText={name => this.setState({ name })}
   value={this.state.name}
/>
</Item>

<Button
   block
   style={{ margin: 10 }}
   onPress={this.addNameToArr.bind(this)}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this :

```
this.setState({
   arr:this.state.arr.concat(this.state.name);
})
```

or  you can use it like this by es6 spread syntax :

```
this.setState({
   arr:[...this.state.arr,this.state.name];
})
```

changed `newName` to `this.state.name` because you are changing `this.state.name` with onchange handler not `newName`

Answer (score 0):

you have binded "addNameToArr" method with Button on press event, and in "addNameToArr" method, first argument you are expecting a "newName" (input field value) value to be passed in. But, as method is bind with an event call, so you are not getting text input value as argument.

Use:

```
addNameToArr() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    arr: prevState.arr.concat(prevState.name)
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your help! your inputs have helped me find the solution to my question. I have altered my jsx code by adding in brackets and passing the argument directly to the arrow function and it worked! [github](https://github.com/myhendry/playground_rn/blob/master/src/screens/Tutorial2Screen.js) contains the code that works.